# How to Video stream from server

Tags: angular, ionic4

How I can stream video from ma live serve and my App did not slow. Can anyone help me to fix that... and Show some content on this video like overlap some divs and elements.

I want to use this plugin to stream I hope did not overlap the element

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media

Comment: It's unclear whether you are asking how to stream video, full stop, or if you are asking how to do it without impacting performance of the the rest of the app.

Comment: I want to make a video app like TicTok.. On the video, some elements overlap and do many things. I upload a video but when I use video tag to show this. then my response rate is not good enough. So I decide to stream video through my live server. @TheHeadRush Thanks for replying please help me to fix this.

Comment: This site is here to help people fix code that doesn't work as intended. Unless you can provide some code, there's not much we can do.

Comment: Can u suggest me to read anything? Who's a help or find out my solution.